# Paypal: Login with paypal to get payerId

Tags: php, authentication, paypal

Currently I'm working on a paypal integration using the paypal php SDK.
When a user successfully finished a payment, paypal will provide me the payerId.

Is it possible to get the same payerId at a later time by letting the user login to paypal again (without a payment). That way I can match the payerId with one I had stored earlier when the payment was finished so I can determine what products the user is entitled to.

I have gone though the available API functions, but it doesn't seem to have this case.
Maybe I'm going about this all wrong, I'm fairly new to this.

Any help is appreciated,

Corjan

Answer (score 0):

Yep. If you integrate with LIPP (log-in-with-paypal) you can have the user log-in without making another payment, then you can retrieve their payerid using oauth.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/

Alternatively, you could just associate the items that user has bought with their account in your own database.